# Обязательно ли почта должна быть привязана к домену для отправки с нее?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dns, smtp

Допустим у меня есть домен и сервер куда он привязан, на нем развернуто веб-приложение с возможностью потверждения регистрации через почту которую я назвал 'no-reply@domain.com' , в мое случае это яндекс почта, я уже привязал на нее домен, но для этого требуется время, и если отправить с этой почты на тот же gmail, письмо приходит с пометкой 'Системе Gmail не удалось подтвердить, что это письмо отправлено из домена' , так вот к чему я веду, письма от аппликэйшна не приходят вообще, а судя по логам они отправляются без ошибок, в приложении я написал smtp с такими конфигами :

```
    config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: 'smtp.yandex.ru',
    tls: true,
    port: 465,
    domain: 'yandex.ru',
    authentication: 'plain',
    enable_starttls_auto: true,
    user_name: Rails.application.secrets.email_provider_username,
    password: Rails.application.secrets.email_provider_password
  }
```

Суть вопроса в том что требуется ли потверждение привязки к домену на яндекс.почте чтобы письма наконец-то доходили? Ибо у меня есть точно такой же проект с другим названием, там все работает на ура. Т.е в коде проблем быть не может.

Comment: У Вас для dev-окружения в конфиге включена опция `config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true `? Чтобы быть уверенным в отсутствии ошибок

Comment: В свое время при привязке smtp яндекса также не уходили письма. Как оказалось, требовалось разок зайти под этим аккаунтом через браузер, потом письма полетели.

Comment: @Yauhen да включена, у себя в яндекс паспорте вижу что я пытался получить доступ к почте, настроил двухфакторку, и пароль для приложения, но письма не доходят.

Answer (score 0):

Вот моя рабочая конфигурация, может поможет

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    user_name: 'mailer@example.com',
    password: 'secret',

    authentication: 'plain',
    address: 'smtp.yandex.ru',
    domain: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 587,

    enable_starttls_auto: true
  }
```